# How do I Display a link inside an if-condition using javascript based on var

Tags: javascript, php

im trying to change the href of my var explanation 11 based on the conditions obtained.

here's the code for the variable

```
if ( savings_budget_aycs > totalexp ) {
    var msg="UNDER";
    var explanation="You still have some excess money after factoring all your expenses in your budget. You may want to start looking at investing your excess money or increasing your savings. Do read out content on";
    var explanation11=" saving and investing";
    var explanation12=" to understand more.";                
    var explanation2="Since you have more money to use from your budget, one option is to increase your savings.";
    var remaining=savings_budget_aycs-totalexp;
} else {
    var msg="OVER";
    var remaining=totalexp-savings_budget_aycs;
    var explanation="This means that your spending has exceeded your income. You will need to make some cutbacks to be able to stay within your budget. Do read our content on";    
    var explanation11=" planning and budgeting";    
    var explanation12=" to understand more.";                
    var explanation2="You are over budget, so try to see what you can cut down on to save some money.";
}
```

and here is where i call the explanation

```
firstTableHtml += "<div class=\'explanation\'>"+explanation+"<a id=\'link-saving\'>"+explanation11+"</a>"+explanation12+"</div>";
```

Comment: What's the problem?  You can do this, since `var` is function scoped, though it could be done cleaner.

Comment: Also what does this have to do with php?

Answer (score 0):

Remove back slashes before the quotes.

```
firstTableHtml += "<div class='explanation'>"+explanation+"<a id='link-saving'>"+explanation11+"</a>"+explanation12+"</div>";
```